# Kotlin showing error when I use I do Any as Int<Int

Tags: kotlin

I want to compare fields of a JSONObject.

Here is the code I am trying:

```kotlin
x = JSONObject()
x.put("num",1)
if(x["num"] as Int < 2){
    print("Good work!")
}
```

Error shown by IDE:

```
Type expected
Expecting a '>
```

Comment: can you put the whole code? Including the declaration of `x` and the full `error` with `stacktrace`?

Comment: I edited OP's question, it looks like parts of the code were lost in the formatting issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current code doesn't work as-is because the compiler sees `Int<42`  and thinks that you're trying to use a type parameter for the `Int` type (like `Int<T>`) which obviously doesn't work for 2 reasons:

- `Type expected` because 42 is not a type
- `Expecting a '>'` because well, there is no `>`

As @Alex.T said, you can disambiguate this by putting `(..)` around the cast expression: `(x["num"] as Int) < 2`.

However, if you're OK with your expression failing at runtime like this, you should instead use a typed getter like [getInt()](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#getInt-java.lang.String-):

```kotlin
val x = JSONObject()
x.put("num", 1)
if (x.getInt("num") < 2) {
    print("Good work!")
}
```

If the value is not an integer, this will fail at runtime with `org.json.JSONException` (as mentioned in the Javadoc linked above). You can catch this exception if you want to handle the error gracefully.

Alternatively you can use a safer option with a default value, like [optInt()](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#optInt-java.lang.String-int-), which will default to the given value if the key is not present in the JSON OR if the value is not a number.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put `x["num"] as Int` into parenthesis, otherwise the compiler will think that you are trying to do `Int < 2` which doesn't really make any sense.

```
val x = JSONObject()
x.put("num", 1)
if ((x["num"] as Int) < 2) {
    print("Good work!")
}
```

But btw, this will throw a `ClassCastException` if the value is not actually an `Int`. It is in your minimal case, but you don't always actually know. In that scenario I would do something like this:

```
val x = JSONObject()
x.put("num", "b")
val num = x["num"]
if (num is Int && num < 2) {
    print("Good work!")
}
```

Comment: Okay, Thanks! This worked. Now do I need to mark the question as solved somehow?

Comment: If you're confident about the structure of the JSON, you can also use `x.getInt("num")` instead of casting (unless we're not talking about `org.json.JSONObject`?)

Comment: +1 to @Joffrey on the `.getInt()`, I'd appreciate if you add that to the answer, or post as an alternative answer, since it is better than the double predicate if statement (with a try/catch, or certainty). Regarding marking something as solved, [there is a stackexchange post on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)